# App Store build crashes, doesn't on testing on Sim or my own device

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, app-store

I have just released an update for my app to the app store. I tested it within the simulater and my own devices and never had an issue. I have since discovered that the updated version crashes, but only on the iPad and only from the app store

The update has made the app universal.

Any help would be great, i dont wanna effect my reting.

Crash Log below

```
Incident Identifier: 36D64A4B-25EF-4352-BEFC-DF4409B48048
CrashReporter Key:   ca77f364943901ada3da44974f547565326b5b64
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         FuelCost [2659]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/4A738AC7-C717-46C2-9469-9B8888B6FE10/FuelCost.app/FuelCost
Identifier:      FuelCost
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-05-14 16:20:31.338 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.2 (8H7)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360ffa1c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e093b4 pthread_kill + 52
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e01bf8 abort + 72
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x363fca64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b2806c _objc_terminate + 104
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x363fae36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x363fae8a std::terminate() + 10
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x363faf5a __cxa_throw + 78
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33b26c84 objc_exception_throw + 64
9   CoreFoundation                  0x303c548a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
10  CoreFoundation                  0x303c54c4 +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
11  UIKit                           0x35aa2a4c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1104
12  UIKit                           0x35aa3e02 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 86
13  UIKit                           0x358ce4c6 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 90
14  UIKit                           0x358c8b02 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 174
15  UIKit                           0x3589d7d0 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1108
16  UIKit                           0x3589d20e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
17  UIKit                           0x3589cc4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
18  GraphicsServices                0x35571e70 PurpleEventCallback + 660
19  CoreFoundation                  0x3039ca90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3039e838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3039f606 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3032febc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3032fdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
24  UIKit                           0x358c7d42 -[UIApplication _run] + 366
25  UIKit                           0x358c5800 UIApplicationMain + 664
26  FuelCost                        0x000022ee main (main.m:14)
27  FuelCost                        0x000022b8 0x1000 + 4792

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361003ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0a6d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36100fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0b032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0c03a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x33d0b5ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0a58a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360fdc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x360fd758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3039d2b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3       CoreFoundation                  0x3039f562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3032febc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3032fdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x34c2627e RunWebThread(void*) + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0930a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e0abb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3e8a148c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x0015bb5c      r7: 0x2fdfe068
    r8: 0x3f039964    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0014ec40     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe05c      lr: 0x32d8f3bb      pc: 0x32ae2a1c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to check here

1. Make sure that all of your files are included in the target, specifically the Nib files.
2. Check to make sure you have nibs included for the iPad.
3. You left out the Binary Images section of the report, but check to make sure these crashing devices aren't jail-broken.

Finally, if you are going to support iPad, I would highly recommend getting a physical one to test on. You could have avoided this otherwise.

Comment: i have a physical one, and it tested it, running it from xcode 4 caused no issues. I have downloaded my app from the app store myself and also get this others are finding, same hardware and i believed the same software, all the files appear to be there as expected.

Comment: Did you test an adhoc build? You can duplicate your distribution scheme and make it ad-hoc, then install through iTunes. Also, are you trying to make it a universal build? Or does the iPad run a iPhone simulated version?